# "I am puzzled by conflicting opinion on [a] coffee."

Tags: grammaticality, indefinite-articles, uncountable-nouns

> - I am puzzled by conflicting opinion on a coffee.
> - I am puzzled by conflicting opinion on coffee.

These sentences are from a syllabus book. And I don't know which one is correct.

Comment: Are you referring to coffee in general, or a particular type/genus/brand/cup of coffee?

Comment: It depends on context. 'a coffee': you're puzzled by a conflict over one particular coffee. Just 'coffee': you're puzzled by a conflict over coffee in general.

Comment: [coffee](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/coffee?q=coffee) and [mass nouns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_nouns). Please rephrase your question so that there is enough context to answer it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "a conflicting opinion" or "conflicting opinions". While "opinion" can be a mass noun, I wouldn't use it as one in this sentence. And [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conflicting+opinions%2Cconflicting+opinion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) seems to agree with me.

Comment: If you are an English Learner, you might be interested in our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There's no confusion. Both are grammatically correct. They mean different things. Check the context -- in a given context, only one of them could be semantically correct. Without context, this is a non-question and is likely to be closed for that reason alone.

Comment: Where is the OP?

Answer (score 5):

*Coffee* is a mass noun, and therefore should not take an indefinite article. But there are constructions in English that exploit and extend this distinction.

In particular, if you **do** use *a/an* with a mass noun like *coffee* (*tea, milk, rice, tofu, beef*, etc), then you are referring to a particular **kind** (brand, variety, version, strain) of whatever that mass noun is.

*I am puzzled by conflicting opinion on **a** coffee.*
 - means that it's **a kind** of coffee that you're talking about, **not** coffee in general.

*I am puzzled by conflicting opinion on coffee.*
 - does not refer to any kind of coffee, but rather to **all** coffee.

> (Note that this procedure can be applied to other kinds of mass nouns, besides food and drink;
>   but when it **does** apply to food and drink, the implications are automatically about eating and drinking)